# To display the post order by modified date in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post

I have to display the posts oder by last modified date. So I used the code bellow.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'numberposts' => '2',
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order'=> 'ASC',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But I could not find any update in the above code. Should i use something else instead of `'orderby' => 'modified'` in the argument.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use `DESC` for `order`.

Try this:

```
 $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type'   => $post_type,
     'numberposts' => '2',
     'orderby'     => 'modified',
     'order'       => 'DESC',
 ));
```

Using `DESC` will give you the latest post first(descending order).

**EDIT:**

As Andrew [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438920/to-display-the-post-order-by-modified-date-in-wordpress/14440877?noredirect=1#comment93150372_14440877), the default value for `order` is `DESC` and can thus be omitted from the code:

```
 $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type'   => $post_type,
     'numberposts' => '2',
     'orderby'     => 'modified',
 ));
```

Comment: The default ordering order is 'DESC' so that line is not actually required.

Comment: I prefer to include `'order' => 'DESC'` when using `orderby` for readability, even though it's not required.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&post_type=$post_type&orderby=modified&order=desc'); ?>
```

Comment: Those are custom post type.